# Is my understanding of partial functions and total functions correct?

Tags: functions, definition, relations

After reading [this Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/264750/), I wanted to know if my understanding of *partial* vs. *total* functions is correct.

$$
\newcommand{\+}{\mkern2mu}
\newcommand{\viff}{\Big\Updownarrow}
\begin{gather*}
f \subseteq A \times B \text{ is a }\textit{partial} \text{ function} \\[5pt]
\viff \\[5pt]
\forall\+ a \in A,\, \forall\+ b \in B,\, \forall\+ c \in B,\; \bigl((a, b) \in f \land (a, c) \in f\+\bigr) \implies b = c. \\[10pt]
f \subseteq A \times B \text{ is a } \textit{total} \text{ function} \\[5pt]
\viff \\[5pt]
\Bigl(\+\forall\+ a \in A,\, \forall\+ b \in B,\, \forall\+ c \in B,\; \bigl((a, b) \in f \+\land\+ (a, c) \in f\+\bigr) \implies b = c.\Bigr) \\[5pt]
\land \\[5pt]
\bigl(\+\forall\+ x \in A,\, \exists\, y \in B,\; (x, y) \in f.\bigr) 
\end{gather*}
$$

In other words,
$$
\begin{aligned}
f \text{ is a } \textit{partial} \text{ function} &\iff f \text{ is a univalent relation.} \\[5pt]
f \text{ is a } \textit{total} \text{ function} &\iff f \text{ is a total and univalent relation.} \\[5pt]
\end{aligned} 
$$

Equivalently(?),

$$
\begin{gather*}
f\+\colon\+ A \to B\+ \text{ is a } \textit{partial} \text{ function} \\[5pt]
\viff \\[5pt]
\forall\+ a \in A,\, \forall\+ b \in B,\, \forall\+ c \in B,\; \bigl(f(a) = b \+\land\+ f(a) = c\bigr) \implies b = c. \\[10pt]
f\+\colon\+ A \to B\+ \text{ is a } \textit{total} \text{ function} \\[5pt]
\viff \\[5pt]
\Bigl(\+\forall\+ a \in A,\, \forall\+ b \in B,\, \forall\+ c \in B,\; \bigl(f(a) = b \+\land\+ f(a) = c\+\bigr) \implies b = c.\Bigr) \\[5pt]
\land \\[5pt]
\bigl(\+\forall\+ x \in A,\, \exists\, y \in B,\; f(x) = y.\bigr)
\end{gather*}
$$

### Are these definitions correct?

#### Also, when is it safe to assume that *function* refers to *total function* in mathematical texts?

Thank you.

Comment: See [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Total,_univalent_relation). In set theoretic terms we have a *relation*, that is a subset of the cartesian product. Then a *function* is a relation that is "univalent" i.e. such that for each element of the domain there is exactly one element associated to it. Example with set of human males: "x is Father of y" is a relation but not a function; "x is Son of y" is a relation that is a function.

Comment: "when is it safe to assume that *function* refers to *total function* in mathematical texts?" Always, at least for modern texts! What you are calling a "total function" is the *definition of "function"*. This "partial" vs "total" function stuff is someone's personal labeling that - in my experience - is not common at all. I've heard your "partial functions" called a "functional relation" before, but this is the first time I run into your terminology. For the last 100-150 years, "function" has meant your "total function". (Before that, it didnt mean a subset of $A\times B$ at all).

Comment: @PaulSinclair I see, thank you.